# Повторный фокус на кнопке

Tags: css, css3

Рисую такую кнопку. Суть в том, что при первом клике, естесственно, срабатывает `:focus` и все, что ему приписано, но, при следующих кликах нет, так как фокус еще остался. Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы событие срабатывало при каждом клике?
[КодПеро](http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/MyRXRj?editors=1100)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300);
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  padding: 50px 0 0;
}

button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: button .7s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

button {
  border: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  font-weight: lighter;
  background: #3F51B5;
  color: #eee;
  transition: all .2s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  outline: none;
}

@keyframes 'button' {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 0 rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 20px rgba(63, 81, 181, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes 'button' {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 0 rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 20px transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div><button>button</button></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Назначать не на фокус, а на выход из активного состояния

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300);
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  padding: 50px 0 0;
}

button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
button:focus:not(:active) {
  animation: button .7s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

button {
  border: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  font-weight: lighter;
  background: #3F51B5;
  color: #eee;
  transition: all .2s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  outline: none;
}

@keyframes 'button' {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 0 rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 20px rgba(63, 81, 181, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes 'button' {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 0 rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), 0 0 0 20px transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div><button>button</button></div>
```